# Extend ClickOnce Signing Certificate

Tags: c#, .net

I have a WPF application developed with VS2019 which updates using ClickOnce but the .pfx certificate only lasts for one year. This means users have to reinstall the app every year instead of using ClickOnce to update it. I've found some C# code (https://github.com/OceanAirdrop/ExtendClickOnceCertificate) developed by @OceanAirdrop and others which will extend the life of a certificate but this generates a SHA-1 certificate instead of SHA-256. Unfortunately Microsoft has deprecated the use of SHA-1 signatures (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/announce/sha1deprecation).

There doesn't appear to be any reference in the code to SHA-1 and I don't know what to change in order to produce a SHA-256 certificate.

How can I change the code to generate an extended SHA-256 certificate?

Comment: If an app is signed with a certificate that is valid at the time of signing, there is NO NEED to re-sign the app or reinstall it after the certificate expires, unless you are rebuilding or making a new version of the app. The users should NEVER have to worry about this.

Comment: @Matthew The issue is I am rebuilding the app after updating it. The previous version does still work but the new version with the new certificate doesn't install, it crashes the previous version when trying to update.